# Open Excel file usint Interop using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have this  code in C# y used to open a Excel file.

```
Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
Excel._Workbook oWB;

String filename = "C:\\plantilla2.xlsx";

oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(filename, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

MessageBox.Show("FIN");
```

This code worked fine two days ago. I have not changed anything and now I get an error in the line where opens the excel file.
First I see a message "Excel is trying to recover information"

And after that I get the exception "Error in remote procedure call. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800706BE)"

I don't know what is going wrong. I have checked the references as explained in this web. http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-open-excel.htm

Comment: I'm sorry I have misspelled the path. The correct path is "C:\\plantilla2.xlsx". An the file is located in that path.

Comment: Try setting `oXL.Visible` = true before opening the workbook.  You may see an error message from Excel that gives you a clue.  Or try opening the Excel file interactively using Excel.  Also use Task Manager to check if you have hidden instances of Excel still running, perhaps from the previous time you ran your application.

Comment: You can try disabling all Excel's Add-ins and see if the error still occurs. That solved it for me.

Comment: Is this a *real* Excel file or a CSV/HTML with a faked xlsx extension?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like RPC service down. Are you insure that service "Remote Procedure Call (RPC)" here "Control Panel\Administrative Tools\Services" have a "Running" state ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what has happened. I have restarted the computer and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection ;
                System.Data.DataSet DtSet ;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand ;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
                MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
                DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
                MyConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }
   }
}
```

See this link.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb.htm